# Which id should i use in Select dropdown = new Select(browser.findElement(By.id(""))); in selenium to select the dropdown values

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Which is the id that I need to use in the below code to access?

code in selenium

```
Select dropdown = new Select(browser.findElement(By.id("")));
```

Code for the drop down

```
<div class="form-inline form-group nb-city-selector">
    <div class="wrapper-demo" style="border-right:0px"> <!-- adding class , dropdown will not work-->
        <div id="nbCitySelector" class="wrapper-dropdown-2" tabindex="1">
            <span class="selectedcity" data-key="mumbai">Mumbai</span>
            <ul class="cityselector dropdown">
                <li><a class="cityoption" data-key="mumbai">Mumbai</a></li>
                <li><a class="cityoption" data-key="bangalore">Bangalore</a></li>
                <li><a class="cityoption" data-key="pune">Pune</a></li>
                <li><a class="cityoption" data-key="chennai">Chennai</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div
```

Comment: Your code is not a select list so you cannot use a select.

Comment: @Mobrockers , Which is the best to use in this case ?

Comment: Do you know which item you want to select? As in, do you know you want to select Mumbai or Bangalore?

Comment: What have you tried and what was the result? Please read the help topics on how to ask a good question. You need to research your own issue, find code samples, etc. and write your own code to solve the issue. If you do all that and still can't figure it out, then come back and edit your question and add notes from the research you did, the code you have tried, and what the result was... any error messages, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Hi please do it like below Take all of the value inside the list

```
List<WebElement> myddval = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id='nbCitySelector']/ul/li"));
```

now on the basis of index do the selection

```
myddval.get(1).click() //to select 2nd option
```

Comment: hi thank u so much , i tried it it didnt return any error and even test passed but it didnt select the value

Comment: hi plz try with this xpath //*[@id='nbCitySelector']/ul/li/a

Comment: hi sorry if its not working can you plz confirm that the dropdown from which you are trying to select a value shows its value only after whne you click on that if yes then try to click on that dd and then select a value form it